# vector of a nonempty set also a vector of the intersection of nonempty sets?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $C1\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C_2\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are two nonempty convex sets such that $C_1\cap C_2 \ne \emptyset$, can we prove the following result? :

If $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vertex of $C_1$ such that $\hat{x} \in C_1 \cap C_2$, then $\hat{x}$  is also a vertex of $C_1 \cap C_2$.

My thoughts so far: $\hat{x} \in C_1 \cap C_2$   is a vertex of $C_1$ then it does not lie in any open line segment connecting two points of $C_1$. Then it certainly does not lie in any open line segment connecting two points of $C_1 \cap C_2$ . Hence it is a vertex of $C_1 \cap C_2$... but I am not certain how to show that x does not lie in any open line segment.. and how to present the proof formally.

Comment: My thoughts so far: x∈C1∩C2  is a vertex of C1 then it does not lie in any open line segment connecting two points of C1. Then it certainly does not lie in any open line segment connecting two points of C1∩C2. Hence it is a vertex of C1∩C2... but I am not certain how to show that x does not lie in any open line segment.. and how to present the proof formally.

Comment: You have been around for a year. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: I have edited your post. Try to copy and paste your comment about your thought to the main question, try to use mathjax as much as you can. It doesn't have to be perfect but you have to start using it. start by surrpiunding mathy object with the dollar signs.

Comment: done sir, your previous edit helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a vertex of $C_1$, then there exists a hyperplane $H$ and a corresponding halfspace $H^+$ such that $H \cap C_1=\{\hat{x}\}$ and $C_1 \subset H^+$.

We claim that the same $H$ works.

Notice that $H \cap (C_1 \cap C_2) \subset H\cap C_1=\{\hat{x}\}$, furthermore, we are given that $\hat{x} \in C_1 \cap C_2$  and $\hat{x} \in H$, hence $\hat{x} \in H \cap (C_1 \cap C_2)$ and we can conclude that $H\cap (C_1 \cap C_2) = \{x\}$.

Clearly $C_1 \cap C_2 \subset C_1 \subset H^+$.

Hence $\hat{x}$ is a vertex of $C_1 \cap C_2$.

Comment: I did think about this but how can we claim that the same Hyperplane H exists for the intersection as well ? And why cant the hyperplane be different for the intersection ?

Comment: I choose the same one of which its existence was promised from $\hat{x}$ being a vertex of $C_1$. You can choose a different one if you can prove that it works.

Comment: can you please explain why $H \cap (C_1 \cap C_2) \subset H\cap C_1=\{\hat{x}\}$

Comment: we are given that $H \cap C_1 = \{ \hat{x}\}$,  and we know that $H \cap (C_1 \cap C_2) = (H \cap C_1) \cap C_2$. we know that in general, we have $A \cap B \subset A$.

Comment: ahhh I see. You are right. Thank you sir!! :)